# Can/will anyone help me with a Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like a formula to auto fill one cell with the same text from another, WHEN a cell next to it has data.

Example, if I enter something into cell D11 then I want E11 to automatically copy E10.

Comment: `=IF(D11<>"",E10,"")` in E11?

Comment: Scott, this worked! Thank you so much! Idk how to mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: @MichaelMorton ,,, you may try this also `=INDEX(E10,1,1*(D11<>""))`   or `=IFERROR(IF(D11<>"", E10), "")`☺

Comment: @ScottCraner, short as it is, you might make it an answer, perhaps adding just a bit of detail. It would be be helpful to others.

Comment: Ramesh Sinha, your first code just automatically adds the same text to that cell without having data in the cell next to it... I only want it added AFTER text has been added to the cell next to it, not before. And your 2nd code is exactly the same as Scott's [with added code before and after], which works perfectly as is. So I'll stick with that one. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: IF function works!

Comment: @Lee yes, it does. The actual quest has been answered by the very first comment, but thank you for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(D11<>"",E10,"") in E11? –
```

Scott Craner